# How do I launch the App Store from my iOS app? Also, how do I link to my application on the store in IOS 12?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios12

This question is already in StackOverflow but there is no update for ios 12.
I have check [Technical Q&A in Apple portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1629/_index.html) but they already mention that

> This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information
>   about Apple SDKs, visit the documentation website.

So, anyone got the latest link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to launch the App Store? What are you trying to do/show? Perhaps you should use `SKStoreProductViewController`.